# How to transform this statement for better performance

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have a very bad performance while building (indexing takes 5 - 7 minutes) since I added following lines into my code.

```
var valuesToPassToDetailViewController = [[String:[String: Any]]]()
var dict = [String:[String: Any]]()
dict = [title as! String:["title":title as! String, "valueD":postValue["value"] ?? "", "valueD":postValue["value"] ?? "","valueD":postValue["value"] ?? "","valueD": postValue["value"] ?? "","valueD": postValue["value"] ?? "","valueD":postValue["value"] ?? "","valueD":postValue["value"] ?? "" ,"valueD": postValue["value"] ?? "", "valueD": postValue["value"] ?? ""]]
self.valuesToPassToDetailViewController.append(dict)
```

Please have in mind that valueD is replacement for Key which is of course with different key values and value is replacement same as one above.

Please help me with this. Thanks for every respond.

Comment: I believe that expression was, quote Playground, too complex to be solved in reasonable time, consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

Comment: And, I know this isn't what you're asking for, but this is a wonderful opportunity to revisit this very curious model.

Comment: I am not sure if you just copied the same repeating value for demonstration purposes, but in its current form, this code won't even compile, since a dictionary cannot have repeating keys.

Comment: Yeah it was for demonstration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Apart from being a bad code practice) You write a code that Swift compiler will processes badly, due to a lot of nesting of literals. (happens also in other piece of code.)
Simpler solution:

As You are repeatingly using the same value:

```
let nonNullValue = postValue["value"] ?? ""

dict = [title as! String : ["title":title,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue ,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue,
                            "valueD": nonNullValue]]
```

will do the job.

If I am allowed, some coding notes:

- use a var for repeating values, doing so not only makes compiler happy, but also it is in general FASTER (especially if You use a.b.c.d() that will produce a call/return.. )
- do not pass generic structures between controls, when read/downloaded, create your class/struct and pass them around.
- is better to add to dict dynamically, and will be easy if You have to read data for example from disk/network.

Hope this can help.

another suggestion:

pass to typealias in this way:

typealias Dict =  [[String:[String: Any]]]

so You can write:

```
    var valuesToPassToDetailViewController2 = Dict()
```

counter-test:

```
    var valuesToPassToDetailViewController = [[String:[String: Any]]]()
    var valuesToPassToDetailViewController2 = Dict()

    valuesToPassToDetailViewController2 = valuesToPassToDetailViewController
```

Comment: Yeah this also worked but I have decided to create structure for my purpose. But I am marking your answer as solution due to complexity.

Comment: nice to hear so. I think in future You will have headaches if using this approach.